# Dealing with shell commands that throw away old output

Tags: linux, ssh, shell

There are a bunch of shell commands that throw away old output. A couple that I have seen are Nose and Hudson. What I mean is that when the program is run, it produces a lot of textual output in the shell, but when you scroll up, you can't see the old output, only the commands you used *before* you even typed the original command.

This is driving me crazy, because important information is being swallowed. How do I make these programs stop doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method that worked for me is doing this:

```
my_command my_args >log 2>&1
```

Which stores all output in a file called `log`.

Then, in a separate shell window, I do this:

```
tail -f log
```

Which shows the log file as `my_command` is writing into it.

Answer (score 2):

That sort of thing is usually the result of a program which manipulates the terminal directly and moves the cursor around on it's own.  For example, that's what editors like vi do - if you try to scroll the shell back after a vi session, you only see the text in the last page of vi output, not anything else you paged through.

Ways to deal with this:

- Use a tool like screen(1) and enable logging (`ctrl-A H`).  Then you can review the log later.  That might show more useful info.
- Try using tee(1) to capture the output as it goes by with `command | tee output.txt`
- Determine how to disable any fancy output mode in the program you are running and force it to spit out plain text.

For that last one there are a few things you can try.  First, look at the arguments to the command and see if there's anything like `-nostty` or anything talking about `dumb terminals`.

You can also try forcing the program to think it's on a dumb terminal like this:

```
TERM=dumb command
```

(assuming bash shell) and that might make the program think it's running on a dumb terminal and cause it to switch back to straight text output.

You can also try feeding the program some input and that might trigger it's simple text output mode:

```
echo blarg | command
```

or maybe

```
echo blargh | command -
```

if the program takes `-` as an indication to read from stdin.

Anyway, experiment with those ideas and you should find some way to get straight text output from the tools you are using.

Comment: I'm already a `screen` user, so I tried that; But the `hardcopy.0` file remains empty. Possibly there is a stderr/stdout confusion?

Comment: I also tried `TERM=dumb`, didn't work.

Comment: `command </dev/null` is another idea. Also, look to see if the program docs make reference to the termcap `ti` and `te` capabilities (terminfo `smcup` and `rmcup`). Changing those may be of some help.